# Find function source in Haskell (workflow)

Tags: haskell, workflow

I'm learning Haskell for a while, so I've decided to inspect some popular project to get a feeling how it looks like in reality and perhaps reverse-engineer the process.

I've picked Hakyll because it does something I'm familiar with and is moderately complex. And then I've stucked immediately with the question: how to backtrace imports?

Say, In JavaScript every import is explicit.

```
let Q = require("Q")         // namespace
let {foo} = require("Q/foo") // value
```

Haskell defaults to

```
import Q
```

which spoils everything at once and people seem to really abuse it.

Now I look at the [tutorial](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/03-rules-routes-compilers.html), then at the source and realize I have no clue where one or another function is located and no clue how to discover it except searching.

Is there some trick to discover this kind of information like making syntax error which would reveal source file or whatever? How do you solve such tasks in your workflow?

Comment: You can search for function names or even signatures in hoogle: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Comment: Note that you can specify explicitly what you want to import by writing `import Q(foo)`. Also: use [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) to search for haskell functions.

Comment: @Bakuriu – specification can't help for reverse-engineering when code is given and predefined.

Comment: @IvanKleshnin You can always do `import qualified Q`, this will **not** pollute the namespace and you have to access all members of `Q` using `Q.foo` etc.

Comment: @Bakuriu sorry, you don't get my question. I know Hs syntax and import rules.

Comment: If your question is "I have a name "xxx" in my code and I want to know what to do" the answer is "hoogle xxx" and it will find you which module defines it and its documentation. Moreover you always always load a module into ghci and using `:info xxx` there.

Comment: @Bakuriu is Hoogle alive? Site footer says it's 2013 and I see no sign of activity (or the opposite) to get an impression.

Comment: @IvanKleshnin Yes, did you try to actually use it?

Comment: @Bakuriu sure. The thing is – how can I immediately tell it's still up to date?

Comment: @IvanKleshnin I dunno, but for example if you search `transformers` you get [this page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers) which shows a 2016 timestamp, so the database is up-to-date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some options which do not require compilable code:

- use [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de)
- use [hoogle at Stackage.org](https://www.stackage.org)

I recommend Stackage's hoogle since its database is loaded with all of Stackage.

If you have working code:

- use the `:i` command in ghci
- use ghc-mod through your editor or command line

As an example of the last two options, suppose that your have a module `Foo.hs` which looks like:

```
module Foo where
import Data.Maybe
...
```

Using `ghci`:

```
$ ghci Foo.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Foo              ( Foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Foo.
*Foo> :i catMaybes
catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]   -- Defined in ‘Data.Maybe’
*Foo>
```

Using `ghc-mod`:

```
$ ghc-mod info Foo.hs catMaybes
catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]   -- Defined in ‘Data.Maybe’
$
```

Comment: I suppose you mean :i will show `-- Defined in ‘GHC.Foo.Bar’` -- that's fine. As for `ghc-mod` – could you provide a Stack equaivalent. I think your answer would be comprehensive with output examples.

Comment: Answer updated. For `stack` use `stack ghci` to get into ghci.

Comment: Still it's unclear how to run `ghc-mod` command without a Haskell platform :(

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Intero for Emacs](http://commercialhaskell.github.io/intero/), it supports the standard "go to definition" shortcut of `M-.`.

Other Intero frontends probably use the standard UI of their editor for this functionality as well; I know there's a [NeoVim frontend](https://github.com/myfreeweb/intero.nvim) already.

Comment: Thank you. IDE is one of the possible options. Anyone aware about availability of this feature in "Haskell for Mac" project?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this kind of Haskell code browsing support in **vim**, you might try Stephen Diehl's nice tutorial [Vim and Haskell in 2016](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/vim_2016.html).

There are a variety of editing environments for Haskell that allow you to query the GHC compiler for information about the code. For example, I use [vim-hdevtools](https://github.com/bitc/vim-hdevtools), and I can open the file `hakyll/src/Hakyll/Main.hs` in **vim**, move the cursor over the `Commands.build` symbol, enter command `:HdevtoolsInfo`, and then GHC will tell me the type of the symbol and where it is defined, and give me the option to jump to definition.

```
Commands.build ::
  Config.Configuration -> Logger.Logger -> Rules a -> IO ExitCode
        -- Defined at hackyll/src/Hakyll/Commands.hs:48:1
```

However, I confess that I did spend a lot of time [getting vim-hdevtools to work](https://github.com/bitc/vim-hdevtools/issues/22).